# (Django) How to run test suite in Travis CI

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, travis-ci

I am having issues running a test suite in a dockerize Django application using  Travis CI. I ran the test suite locally without any issue i.e after using:

```
docker-compose up --build -d 

docker-compose run django --no-deps python manage.py test polls
```

This is my github repo: https://github.com/bgreatfit/Docker_django
Everything works(test suite) fine on my local machine that contains the Dockerized Django Application. While in Travis the build creation is successful but test suite doesn't run. This is the last line of the output on Travis:

```
docker_django-mysql | Version: '5.6.43'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

This is my travis url:https://travis-ci.org/bgreatfit/Docker_django

This is my travis.yaml file

```
sudo: required
services:
    - docker

before_install:
    - docker-compose up   -d
    - docker ps


script:
    - docker-compose run django python manage.py test polls
```

This is my docker-compose file

```
version: "3.1"



services:

    django:
      build: ./app
      container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}-django
      command: gunicorn first_project.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
      volumes:
        - ./app:/app
        - static_volume:/app/static
      expose:
         - 8000
      depends_on:
        - mysql

    mysql:
      image: mysql:5.6
      container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}-mysql
      volumes:
        - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=docker_root
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=docker_django_db
        - MYSQL_USER=dbuser
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=dbpw
      ports:
        - "8306:3306"


    phpmyadmin:
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
      container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}-phpmyadmin
      environment:
          - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      restart: always
      ports:
             - 8082:80
      volumes:
             - /session

    nginx:
      build: ./nginx
      container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}-nginx
      volumes:
           - static_volume:/app/static
      ports:
           - 1337:80
      depends_on:
          - django


volumes:
  db-data:
  static_volume:
```

My docker file :

```
FROM python:3.6
# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# set work directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install python mysql client
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install libmysqlclient-dev \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*

# install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


# copy project

# copy entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

# copy project
COPY. /app/

# run entrypoint.sh
RUN ["chmod","+x","/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

My expectation is that after creating the build on Travis I should see the test suite output: e.g No of tests and if it is successful

Comment: One small thing to note is that it does not make sense to write `docker-compose up -d` before you do a `docker-compose run` command. The `run` command starts a new container. If you want to use an existing container that is up and running use `docker-compose exec`. Not sure if this solves your issue though.